# Give leading tiny stretch in order to balance multicols

Tags: luatex, multicol

I would like to give leading the ability to stretch a tiny amount in cases where it would help balance the columns of a `multicols` environment. For example, the following MWE produces the following output:

```
\documentclass[a5]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{leading}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\lorem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\par}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem
\lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem
\lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem
\lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem
\lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Unbalanced columns]

You can see that the columns are slightly unbalanced at the bottom. I know usually it is not at all a good idea to have leading vary across a document, but given that the amount of extra leading required to balance the second column would be so small, I can't help but think that this would be a perfect time to break that typographic rule.

Letting `parskip` stretch is not an option for me.

I'm using LuaLaTeX.

Comment: you can add a stretch component to baselineskip  but it is the parskip that is pushing you off the grid, why can't you make parskip flexible, which is the far more common solution (or make parskip a fixed \baselineskip)

Comment: note that `\setlength{\parskip}{0.1em}` sets parskip to .1em based on the (mostly unspecified) font current at that point  in the preamble, it doesn't make parskip dependent on the font used in the paragraph

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was being a bit sneaky about this, but the truth is that my parskip *is* flexible, but not enough to solve this issue—and I can't make it stretch further (and it is less than \baselineskip. That's just how this document has to be). For the MWE, obviously letting parskip be flexible solves the problem easily, so I wanted to avoid solutions which took advantage of that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the info re: the length of parskip, I unthinkingly chose ems as the unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{leading}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\lorem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\par}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.1em}% somewhat unsafe setting based on fonts here (which are often reset at begin{document}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\setlength\baselineskip{1\baselineskip plus 1pt minus .5pt}% I wouldn't do this ...
\lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem
\lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem
\lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem
\lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem
\lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks—I should have thought to do this myself. I only require a stretch of `plus 0.01pt` in my document to solve the issue... hopefully this will not cause any further problems.